# How to assign hierarchical data in multiple rowSpan

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, html-table

I have an issue with hierarchical data in multiple rowSpan. I. think I can make this kind of table frame below. But when hierarchical multiple data comes in, It is hard to refine the data. I only can think using 'map' method for this. Does anyone have an good idea for iterating data?

Data form should be like this below

```
 CHOICE_CHECKUP_MOCK = [
{
    category_name: "ChoiceA",
    possible_count: 1,
    checkup_list: [
        {
            middle_checkup_name: "ChoiceA middle list1",
            checkups: [
                {
                    name: "SubClass 1-1",
                    code: "code 1-1",
                    description: "description 1-1",
                    price: 0,
                },
                {
                    name: "subClass 1-2",
                    code: "code 1-2",
                    description: "description 1-2",
                    price: 0,
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            middle_checkup_name: "ChoiceA middle list2",
            checkups: [
                {
                    name: "checkups_name3",
                    code: "checkups_code3",
                    description: "checkups_description3",
                    price: 0,
                },
                {
                    name: "checkups_name4",
                    code: "checkups_code4",
                    description: "checkups_description4",
                    price: 0,
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
},
{
    category_name: "ChoiceB",
    possible_count: 1,
    checkup_list: [
        {
            middle_checkup_name: "ChoiceB middleClassList1",
            checkups: [
                {
                    name: "SubClass 1-1",
                    code: "code 1-1",
                    description: "description 1-1",
                    price: 0,
                },
                {
                    name: "subClass 1-2",
                    code: "code 1-2",
                    description: "description1-2",
                    price: 0,
                },
                {
                    name: "subClass 1-2",
                    code: "code 1-2",
                    description: "description 1-2",
                    price: 0,
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            middle_checkup_name: "ChoiceB MiddleClassList2",
            checkups: [
                {
                    name: "checkups_name3",
                    code: "checkups_code3",
                    description: "checkups_description3",
                    price: 0,
                },
                {
                    name: "checkups_name4",
                    code: "checkups_code4",
                    description: "checkups_description4",
                    price: 0,
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
},
```

And should be table looks like this
[image: multiple rowSpan table]

I did so far is if I want to combine several rows, add rowSpan and put number as much as I want in the first td in tr. and that tr should be the first row will be combined.

For now that is just hard coding data. I want to refine that data for suitably.

If someone know how to refine data for that table, please let me know.... Thank you